# Scrollable layout in Alert Dialog with a button sticked to the bottom (using Constraint Layout)

Tags: android, scrollview, android-alertdialog, android-constraintlayout

I have to show an Alert Dialog with only the text area is scrollable and a button sticked to the bottom of the dialog which is not part of the scrollable area (button should be always visible).

[image]

I found a solution using RelativeLayout in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/9326544/1554537.

But I need to use Constraint Layout.

When I used the constraint layout, the scroll view always pushes the button out of the screen.

Here is the constraint layout I tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingStart="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    android:paddingEnd="30dp"
    android:paddingBottom="25dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/title"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bodyTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:text="@string/body_msg"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/titleTextView" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Code for showing Alert Dialog,

```
val view = this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.scroll_layout, null)
            val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setView(view)
                .create()
            dialog.show()
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!